# How to populate fields with data based on the path selected from PyQt5 QTreewView

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview

I have the following tree view structure with the root index displaying only the items within the imaging folder. In my UI, as shown in the first image, I have the tree view on the right and some fields to populate on the left according to the path being click. If I click on John's data, the user field gets data from a json file and populates it. if I click on either sample 1 or 2, it gets their own data from another json in their respective path. same goes for scans.

Another scenario is that lets say I click the "+" icon on the tree view and expand it all the way to the scan data and click on a file within it, the code should automatically get the path and populate user, sample and scan for the selected scan data. Whenever I click on another user or a content within another user, it should replace the current data with the new one.

One other thing. The fields should only populate based on how deep the path is selected. If I click on a sample, it should only populate the user and that sample living the scan field blank and so on

What would be the best way to implement these functions? If I were populating only on field, it would have been fine but doing all three is a problem

[image][image]

I tried doing something like this for the user field, but I can already see some problem going this route and I also don't think it is very efficient either.

Any help on how to do this will be greatly appreciated

I started working along these line as shown in the test script below, but this only works assuming we click the folders linearly. Is there a better way to go about it?

**Test Code**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QFileSystemModel,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QTreeView,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QLineEdit,
    QWidget)

import os
import json

class Treeview(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.startPath = "C:/Users/Sorin/Imaging_Test_Folder"

        startPathList = os.path.normpath(self.startPath).split(os.path.sep)
        self.startPathLen = len(startPathList)
        self.currentPath = self.startPath

        self.treeView = QTreeView()
        self.tree_model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.tree_model.setRootPath(self.startPath)
        self.treeView.setModel(self.tree_model)
        self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.tree_model.index(self.startPath))
        self.treeView.doubleClicked.connect(self.displayInfo)

        self.lineEdit1 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit2 = QLineEdit()

        self.lineEdit3 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit4 = QLineEdit()

        self.lineEdit5 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit6 = QLineEdit()

        editonelayout = QHBoxLayout()
        editonelayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit1)
        editonelayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit2)

        edittwolayout = QHBoxLayout()
        edittwolayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit3)
        edittwolayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit4)

        editthreelayout = QHBoxLayout()
        editthreelayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit5)
        editthreelayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit6)

        vlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        vlayout.addLayout(editonelayout)
        vlayout.addLayout(edittwolayout)
        vlayout.addLayout(editthreelayout)

        mainWidget = QWidget()
        layout = QHBoxLayout(mainWidget)
        layout.addLayout(vlayout)
        layout.addWidget(self.treeView)

        self.setGeometry(0,0,900,500)
        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)

    def displayInfo(self, item):
        """ Populates the left feilds with data according to the clicked path"""

        path_index = self.treeView.currentIndex()
        self.currentPath = self.tree_model.filePath(path_index)

        if os.path.isfile(self.currentPath):
            current_folder_path = os.path.dirname(self.currentPath)
        elif os.path.isdir(self.currentPath):
            current_folder_path = self.currentPath

        currentPathList = os.path.normpath(current_folder_path).split(os.path.sep)
        currentPathLen = len(currentPathList)

        if (currentPathLen - self.startPathLen) == 1:
            self.clearEdits()
            path = os.path.join(current_folder_path,"study_data.json")
            with open(path) as study_file:
                study_data = json.load(study_file)

            self.lineEdit1.setText(currentPathList[-1])
            self.lineEdit2.setText(study_data["study_note"])

            study_file.close()

        elif (currentPathLen - self.startPathLen) == 2:
            self.lineEdit3.clear()
            self.lineEdit4.clear()
            self.lineEdit5.clear()
            self.lineEdit6.clear()

            path = os.path.join(current_folder_path,"sample_data.json")
            with open(path) as sample_file:
                sample_data = json.load(sample_file)

            self.lineEdit3.setText(currentPathList[-1])
            self.lineEdit4.setText(sample_data["sample_notes"])

            sample_file.close()

        elif (currentPathLen - self.startPathLen) == 3:
            path = os.path.join(current_folder_path,"scan_data.json")
            with open(path) as scan_file:
                scan_data = json.load(scan_file)

            self.lineEdit5.setText(currentPathList[-1])
            self.lineEdit6.setText(scan_data["scan_notes"])

            scan_file.close()

    def clearEdits(self):

        self.lineEdit1.clear()
        self.lineEdit2.clear()
        self.lineEdit3.clear()
        self.lineEdit4.clear()
        self.lineEdit5.clear()
        self.lineEdit6.clear()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = Treeview()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why don't you use QFileSystemModel?

Comment: I forget to include that. That's what I'm using. The tree view gets all data from the QFilesystemModel

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: I'll make short script for it and update my question

Comment: I just updated my post with a sample code of how I was going to approach the issue